# Using nested if giving a specific answer in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am looking for a compressed code that will give me the exact answer to what error I am looking for.

I have here an example of **Raw Data** which is the one that is sent to us, and the **Processed Data** which is the data entered on the database. That is manual labor typing so I am looking for the possible mistyped words before uploading.

At the moment, I use something like the **Errors Found** table to detect which field or word does not match the original file. The formula is not as it is, but should be close - yellow highlight

```
=IF(H4=VLOOKUP(G4,A4:E6,2,0),H4,"Wrong")
```

[image: Hello]

As per screenshot above, the **Errors Found** table is something I create just to compare the raw and processesd data. It works, but its too much work for us.
I am looking for something that automatically looks up the difference between the two.. in which case something like this.

[image]

I am trying to work out something like this:

`=IF(VLOOKUP(EUEL)=EUEL,TRUE: NO ERROR, FALSE: NAME)` - This only gets the first cell. The formula needs to loop/look into all cells in the row. I tried something like this until the Age cell. Here's what I did:`=IF(G3=VLOOKUP(G3,A3:E5,1,0),IF(H3=VLOOKUP(G3,A3:E5,2,0),"TRUE","AGE"),"N/A")` - the true and age will be another if condition if this goes through and I have like 20+ cells each row.

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Are you okay with VBA solution?

Comment: @Mrig yep, does not matter to me, as long as it can present what I am looking for, but I will still wait for other answers that uses excel formulas so that everyone on my team can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.
The code will -

1. accept the table of any size, so you don't have to worry about number of columns
2. dynamically read the headers
3. will display the column names in errors table as required

   ```
   Sub Compare_Table()

       Dim oldTable As Range, newTable As Range, errorTable As Range, i As Integer, J As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
       Dim lasRow As Long, lastColumn As Long, colCntr As Long
       Dim col As New Collection, colHeader As New Collection
       Dim str As String
       Dim r As Long, c As Long

       On Error Resume Next
       Set oldTable = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Raw Data", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
       Set newTable = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Processed Data", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
       Set errorTable = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select a Cell for Error Table", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)

       i = oldTable.Rows.Count
       J = oldTable.Columns.Count

       r = oldTable.Offset(-1, 0).Row
       c = oldTable.Offset(-1, 0).Column

       lastColumn = oldTable.Cells(oldTable.Count).Column

       'adding items in collection
       For colCntr = c To lastColumn
           colHeader.Add Cells(r, colCntr).Value, CStr(colCntr)
       Next colCntr

       'displaying error table
       Cells(errorTable.Cells.Row, errorTable.Cells.Column) = "Errors Found"
       Cells(errorTable.Cells.Row, errorTable.Cells.Column).Font.Bold = True
       Cells(errorTable.Cells.Row, errorTable.Cells.Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 15

       For m = 1 To i
           For n = 1 To J
               If oldTable.Cells(m, n) <> newTable.Cells(m, n) Then
                   'adding discrpencies in collection
                   col.Add n
               End If
           Next n

           'creating error string
           For c = 1 To col.Count
               If str = "" Then
                   str = colHeader(col(c))
               Else
                   str = str & ", " & colHeader(col(c))
               End If
           Next c

           'displaying error string
           If str = "" Then
               Cells(errorTable.Cells.Row + m, errorTable.Cells.Column) = "No errors found"
           Else
               Cells(errorTable.Cells.Row + m, errorTable.Cells.Column) = str
           End If

           'removing items from collection and string
           Set col = Nothing
           Set col = New Collection
           str = ""
       Next m

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: @AdorableVB - check this answer, this should work for you.

Comment: took me a while to figure it out. but it works.
you didn't mention that I need to select the tables without the headers. Anyway, thanks a lot!
one more thing, can this be used from 2 different excel files, instead of 2 tables from same worksheet?

Comment: Apologies, forgot to mention about the header. This can be used only in the same workbook. Though you can compare the table in two different worksheets in the same workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I already have a solution ready with me which will highlight the discrepancies in the table processed data.

```
Sub Compare_Table()

    Dim oldTable As Range, newTable As Range, errorTable As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim LasRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oldTable = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Raw Data", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
    Set newTable = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Processed Data", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
    Set errorTable = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select a Cell for Error Table", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)

    i = oldTable.Rows.Count
    j = oldTable.Columns.Count

    For m = 1 To i
        For n = 1 To j
            If oldTable.Cells(m, n) = newTable.Cells(m, n) Then
                Cells(errorTable.Cells.Row - 1 + m, errorTable.Cells.Column - 1 + n) = newTable.Cells(m, n)
            Else
                Cells(errorTable.Cells.Row - 1 + m, errorTable.Cells.Column - 1 + n).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                Cells(errorTable.Cells.Row - 1 + m, errorTable.Cells.Column - 1 + n) = "Wrong"
            End If

        Next n
    Next m

End Sub
```

Comment: tried your code, it works, but its the same as what I am using right now, "identifying where there are discrepancies" - in which case I needed to create a new table just to find those error. I wanted something like - if(vlookup(this), true, what is the error
just something that will instantly tell me that there is an error there. Sorry if I can't explain well. But instead of doing the Errors Found, I wanted something like the last picture.

Comment: I think now I understood what you are asking for. In result you want two tables to be displayed. Table 1 for discrepancies (by displaying wrong in respective cell) and Table 2 for listing the column names for each row. Is my assumption right?

Comment: `Else
`Cells(errorTable.Cells.Row - 1 + m, errorTable.Cells.Column - 1 + n).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
`'here, instead of making a new table, coloring it yellow..
`'can you make a table saying that -- at this row this is an error.
`'say.. in this row, age is wrong
`'in the next row gender, status is wrong
`Cells(errorTable.Cells.Row - 1 + m, errorTable.Cells.Column - 1 + n) = "Wrong"
`End If